# Why do you still need to use the class if it is in laravel aliases?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

Why do you still need to say:

`use MyClass\Table\Facades\Table`;

at the top of a laravel controller

even if you have specified it in `app/config/app.php`

```
'aliases' => [
    'Table'     => MyClass\Table\Facades\Table::class,
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't?

```php
'aliases' => [
    'MyClass' => Some\Vendor\Something\Facades\MyClass::class,
]
```

Then you can do

```php
use Myclass;

class MyController extends Controller {
    public function fetch($id) {
        return MyClass::find(1)
}
```